# Why do I come across some 'object' in somebody else's code?

Tags: python

This code I found somewhere in the Internet:

```
class Superclass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print ('SuperClass: Do something')

class Subclass(Superclass):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Subclass, self).__init__()
        print ('SubClass: Do something else')

test = Subclass()
```

So, 'object' in 'class Superclass(object)' is unnecessary in my opinion. Well, I can remove it, and the program works fine as well.

The same we can see for example in Python's Observer pattern here:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern
```

Could you comment on what this 'object' is and what it is here for.

Answer (score 1):

In Python2, declaring a class is derived from `object` is necessary to make the class [a new-style class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54867/190597). Otherwise, it is a classic class. `super` only works properly with new-style classes, so in Python2, `Superclass` must derive from `object` for the `super` call in `Subclass` to work.

In Python3, all classes are new-style. So using `object` is unnecessary.